# How can I remove "gratuitous" spaces in print()? Should I use printf or format?

Tags: python, printing, printf, space

this bit of code:

```
   print( field_list)
   for column in field_list:
        print( column, '\t', row[field[column]])
```

produces this output where spaces have been replaced with periods; e.g.   `"sed 's/ /./g"`

```
['mnm',.'first',.'plus4']
mnm.    .Mr.&.Mrs
first.  .Joe.&.Katy
plus4.  ..

['mnm',.'first',.'plus4']
mnm.    .Mr.&.Mrs
first.  .Steve.&.Melissa
plus4.  ..
```

the `column` exhibits a trailing space, and the data item: *row[field[column]]* a leading space.

How may these be eliminated?

I tried tinkering with a `column.rstrip(' ')` and an `lstrip(' ')` on the data to no avail. Also, the leading space in the 2nd and 3rd items in the field_list is not rendered on output.  This confuses me, since it's replaced with a trailing space.

I'm loathe to filter the python output with a simple `sed` filter:  `s/<space><tab><space>/<tab>/` and would like to complete the job in python.

In full disclosure, I'm restarting with python.

```
    print( field_list)
    for column in field_list:
        print( column, row[field[column]], sep='\t')
```

produced

```
['mnm',.'first',.'plus4']
mnm Mr.&.Mrs
first   Joe.&.Katy
plus4   .
```

thanks to DarkKnight for the *sep* suggestion

Comment: Multiple values passed to *print()* will by default be separated by a single space. You can modify this behaviour by passing your preferred value with the *sep* keyword

Comment: Are you sure this is a real thing, and not just an artifact of the way your terminal (or whatever you're seeing this output in) displays spaces? For example, if I turn on "display whitespace" in notepad++, it shows dots instead of spaces (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb7xf.png). It seems very strange to me that spaces are magically replaced by another character when printing.

Comment: not magically replaced; I used the sed command to expose them.

Comment: You can add `sep=''` to the calls to `print`, but it would make more sense to construct the specific tab-delimeted string you want as a single argument. If you are trying to construct a CSV file, use the `csv` module.